# Azcopy command issue with parameters

Tags: azure-storage, azure-cli, azure-storage-account, azcopy, azure-storage-files

I'm using Azcopy within a shell script to copy blobs within a container from one storage account to another on Azure.
Using the following command -

`azcopy copy "https://$source_storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/$container_name/?$source_sas" "https://$dest_storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/$container_name/?$dest_sas" --recursive`

I'm generating the SAS token for both source and destination accounts and passing them as parameters in the command above along with the storage account and container names.

On execution, I keep getting this error ->

```
failed to parse user input due to error: the inferred source/destination combination could not be identified, or is currently not supported
```

When I manually enter the storage account names, container name and SAS tokens, the command executes successfully and storage data gets transferred as expected. However, when I use parameters in the azcopy command I get the error.

Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below PowerShell Script

```
param
(
    [string] $source_storage_name,
    [string] $source_container_name,
    [string] $dest_storage_name,
    [string] $dest_container_name,
    [string] $source_sas,
    [string] $dest_sas
    
)

.\azcopy.exe copy "https://$source_storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/$source_container_name/?$source_sas" "https://$dest_storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/$container_name/?$dest_sas" --recursive=true
```

**To execute the above script you can run the below command.**

```
.\ScriptFileName.ps1 -source_storage_name "<XXXXX>" -source_container_name "<XXXXX>" -source_sas "<XXXXXX>" -dest_storage_name "<XXXXX>" -dest_container_name "<XXXXXX>" -dest_sas "<XXXXX>"
```

I am Generating SAS token for both the Storage from here . Make Sure to Check all the boxes as i did in the picture.

[image]

OutPut ---
[image]

Comment: @SD4 glad to be help.