# Copying folders from S3 to an Azure Storage Blob and receiving "cannot list objects, access is denied" error. Anyone else have this and resolve it?

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

I've confirmed that my S3 credentials are set correctly and even tried full permissions on the bucket and still receive the same message. On the Azure side, I've added Storage Blob Data Owner permissions to my account and can list files I manually upload through the portal with the credentials I used (signing in through AAD rather than using a token).

Any help is appreciated here.

[image]

Comment: You may missing to put Source SAS and Destination SAS for your storage account: Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617943/azcopy-command-issue-with-parameters/70621085#70621085) which i have answered for Azure You can take reference from this.

Comment: We're using Azure AD for authorization rather than SAS tokens

Comment: This may be issue from AWS side.Please try to give more permissions in [AWS policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-objects) on S3   . [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774798/accessdenied-for-listobjects-for-s3-bucket-when-permissions-are-s3). Then try to do copy with latest az copy version (say v10.12). [reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/558#issuecomment-523734224)

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out there were no issues with either the Azure or AWS configuration. Trying the same commands in a linux VM worked perfectly. If you're experiencing this error it may be an issue with the AWS CLI or some other local config.